# Zabbix не помнимает, что компьютер пользователя выключен в нерабочее время и сигнализирует, что связи нет. Как научить понимать что ПК выключен?

Tags: zabbix, icmp

Когда нет пинга между Zabbix и ПК пользователя — приходит уведомление.
Но, ПК может быть выключен и уведомления, что связи нет. Как заставить Zabbix понимать, что ПК выключался [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чём, с вашей точки зрения, должно выражаться такое «понимание»? напишите это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].